# Accidentally deleted tomcat `webapps` folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat, java

I have accidentally deleted the `webapps` folder in tomcat. I had 2 web applications there deployed as `.war` files and the default tomcat folder, "Root", "manager", "host-manager", "examples" and "docs".

Since I am on cloud amazon EC2 instance (ubuntu) and I have no use of tomcat manager, can I simply create a new directory manually called `webapps` and copy and paste the `.war` files of my projects?

Will this work or is this subjected to break something at some point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work.  shutdown all the tomcat process. create webapps folder give correct permission and ownership. then copy  .war build in webapps and start the service. 
Better if you are having copy of webapps folder restore  it directly.